# Imprimir PDF con Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf

Necesito imprimir un PDF desde una url pero soy incapaz de hacerlo. No me vale con que abra el PDF en una pestaña a parte, necesito que o se imprima directamente al pulsar sobre un botón o similar o que se abra dentro de un popup el pdf para poder imprimirse desde ahí.

He probado con la librería: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

Pero me está dando un error al abrir el pdf:

> TypeError: window.webViewerLoad is not a function
>
> Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Actualizo con el código..

```
<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer [src]="'urlconpdf.pdf'" useBrowserLocale="true" delayFirstView="2000">
```

Estoy un poco perdido ya, no sé como seguir con esto. Alguién ha tenido que enfrentarse a esto antes?

Un saludo!

Comment: Sin ver el código no podemos ver qué te produce el fallo

Comment: Hola @PabloLozano ahora actualizo.. pero no hay apenas nada que ver, instalación de la librería y llamada a la misma básicamente.

Comment: He estado mirando un poco y parece [un bug de la librería](https://github.com/stephanrauh/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/issues/20).

Comment: Manda narices, yo he estado mirando "un mucho" y se me ha pasado por completo este bug abierto en el proyecto y mira que me lo he pateado de arriba abajo. Gracias!